# "Our auto cradles operate on DC power, So there is no chance of electricity shock. It's 100% safe for babies as well as for parents." Is true?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, safety

I am not electrical engineer but I have a doubt that DC power can give shock to human or not. I am trying to buy an electronic product which i have to plug with power. This will be for a baby so i want to make sure that there is no safety concern.

[Here](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07K22VVQ3/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza) is the product.

I hope the question won't be down voted or removed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A dc voltage can certainly kill you. As with ac it depends on what the voltage is and the current it can supply.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't buy anything from Shamazon that is electrical in nature. Been there, had kids get shocks due to shoddy workmanship. Plus, where is the quality assurance?

Comment: DC or AC matters very little. What voltage does it operate on and how is it isolated from the mains, if at all?

Comment: Just had a look at the product and it's a total death trap. That speed controller is nothing more than a thyristor dimmer, supplying mains voltage DC to the motor and the stricture is not grounded. DO NOT BUY IT!

Comment: DC is actually more dangerous than AC at mains voltage. It can act on your motor nerves to clamp your muscles shut on the voltage source while AC is more likely to  jolt you away. (A properly isolated 12V supply would be safe; that doesn't look like one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are possible safety concerns.  This device is powered by a control box that plugs into the mains. (from the listing, image looks a little render-y):

[image]

If the device is poorly made there are possible shock (and fire) hazards. For example, if the isolation (if there is any) between mains and DC output is faulty. If there is no isolation then you are depending on the motor winding insulation for your life. A parent or nanny touching the metal frame and a grounded metal object with the other hand or bare feet could be subjected to a fatal shock if the isolation is faulty, as just one example.

Appears to be a 2-pin mains plug (no ground). It's also not clear to me that there is a shield protecting little fingers from the back of the drive mechanism. An older sibling in the 'cruising' stage can be expected to lift himself or herself up using the frame so they would be in full contact with anything that's exposed.

There is no indication in the listing of any safety agency testing (UL, CSA, TÜV or whatever agencies that India has domestically), which does not engender much confidence. As well as electrical and pinch hazard safety testing, materials (toxicity, flammability, etc.) could be of concern.

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful